# SystemVerilog: is it possible to make `define based on value of a package parameter?

Tags: system-verilog, preprocessor-directive

Is it possible to specify a `define parameter based on a value of a package parameter? F.ex:

```
if(pa_ProductSetup::MODULE_SET=="A") 
`define MODULE_A_INCLUDED
```

And use it later to select which parts of the code to compile:?

```
`ifdef(MODULE_A_INCLUDED)

`endif
```

Best regards,

Elena H.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this. Preprocessor directives are parsed before any other SystemVerilog syntax. You can use generate-if blocks to control what gets compiled, but generate block are much more restricted as far as what is allowed inside them

```
if (pa_ProductSetup::MODULE_SET=="A") begin :generate_block
// put the code here you would have wanted inside the `ifdef
end :generate_block
```